# Ruby on Rails: Linking to resource show page results in No Route Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, link-to

I have been working on my first project in rails and have stumbled across a problem while using tags. I have it working so when the user clicks a tag it shows all entries associated with that tag. However when I try to make those names link to the show page for that entry I receive this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"characters", :anime_id=>#<Character id:     1, name: "Kamina", description: "Badass", occupation: "Team Dai-Gurren", anime_id: 1, created_at: "2013-06-06 01:00:57", updated_at: "2013-06-06 03:28:20">}
```

I have been trying to fix it for hours but have had no luck. If anyone has some advice to solve this problem it would be much appreciated.

Controller:

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController

  def create
@anime = Anime.find(params[:anime_id])
@character = @anime.characters.create(params[:character])
redirect_to anime_path(@anime)
  end

  def show
@anime = Anime.find(params[:anime_id])
@character= @anime.characters.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
@anime = Anime.find(params[:anime_id])
@characters= @anime.characters.all
  end

  def tagged

    @anime = Anime.find(params[:anime_id])

    if params[:tag].present?
  @characters = @anime.characters.tagged_with(params[:tag])
else
  @characters = @anime.characters.postall
    end

  end

end
```

Routes:

```
Animedb::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :animes do
resources :characters
  end

  match 'tagged' => 'characters#tagged', :as => 'tagged'
```

View:

```
<h1>Listing Characters</h1>

    <table>
  <tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Season</th>
<th>Genre</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
```

```
<% @characters.each do |character| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to character.name, anime_character_path(character) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:

```
anime_character_path(@anime, character)
```

You need to pass anime as well as character object.